# use identifying symbols to identify and edit line/string, then append line/string to previous line in file

Tags: sed, awk, append, delimiter

Using standard linux utilities (sed and awk, I am guessing)

Sorry about the vague title, I don't really know how to describe the request much better.  An easier way to do so is to provide a simple example.  I have a file with the following content:

```
      www.example.com
      johnsmith@gmail.com
      fredflintstone@gmail.com
      bettyboop@gmail.com
      www.example2.com
      kylejohnson@gmail.com
      www.example3.com
      chadbrown@gmail.com
      joshbeck@gmail.com
      www.example4.com
      tomtom@gmail.com
      jeffjeffries@gmail.com
      billnorman@gmail.com
      stankubrick@gmail.com
      andrewanders@gmail.com
```

So, what I want to do is convert the above to:

```
      www.example.com,johnsmith@gmail.com,fredflintstone@gmail.com,bettyboop@gmail.com
      www.example2.com,kylejohnson@gmail.com
      www.example3.com,chadbrown@gmail.com,joshbeck@gmail.com,
      www.example4.com,tomtom@gmail.com,jeffjeffries@gmail.com,billnorman@gmail.com,stankubrick@gmail.com,andrewanders@gmail.com
```

I am thinking that the easiest thing to do would be to execute something along the lines of:  if the line contains an "@" symbol, input a comma at the beginning of the line/string and then append that line/string to the preceding line.  Anyone have any ideas?  It would be simpler, I think, if there were a uniform number of email addresses associated with each website, but this is not the case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can we rely on that there will always be the equivalent of www.example*.com separating the groups that you want to put on one line? I would think of this problem as 'if there is NO @ sign on the current line, we're starting to create a new list, append any following records onto this current line, until we find the next line without @ sign'. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach

```
awk '{s=/@/?",":"\n";printf s"%s",$0}' file

www.example.com,johnsmith@gmail.com,fredflintstone@gmail.com,bettyboop@gmail.com
www.example2.com,kylejohnson@gmail.com
www.example3.com,chadbrown@gmail.com,joshbeck@gmail.com
```

`s=/@/?",":"\n"` Does line contain `@` yes set `s=","` no set `s="\n"` (newline).

`printf s"%s",$0` print `$0` using `s` as format.  If line has `@` print newline, then `$0`, if not print  `,`, then `$0`

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Now I will have to dig into awk a bit more to figure out why.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk program:

```
/^[:space:]*www\./ {
    if (f) {print line}
    f=1; line=$0; 
    next
}
f {
    line=(line "," $0)
}
```

Comment: An url does not need to contain `www`, but all email does have `@`